# "By / with the name" in this context

Tags: prepositions

I use this application **with / by** the name of X, but my real name is something else.

Which is more appropriate?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Neither **with** nor **by** is appropriate.

If it's not your real name, you are using the application UNDER the name (pseudonym, alias etc)

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/pseudonym

https://blog.contena.co/the-freelancers-guide-to-writing-under-a-pseudonym/